# How to put a p:commandButton inside a p:panel footer

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to put a primefaces commandButton inside a panel footer but it seems that primefaces panel footers take only text, i want to do something like that :

```
            <p:panel id="JunglePanel" header="Jungle" footer="<p:commandButton action="#{JungleBean.navigate}"
                            ajax="false" value="Navigate"">
           </p:panel>
```

but it didn't work, does anyone know how to achieve that ?

Comment: Please do your homework, I see many questions that answers can be found so easily...

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie OP's last question concerned *header*, and not *footer*, so that's basically a very different question :)

Comment: I just mean that many questions can be answered with first or second link by searching...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want footer have the same css as header, you can apply header's css to footer, i have tested and it work:

```
         <h:form>
            <p:panel id="JunglePanel" header="Jungle">
                <f:facet name="footer" >
                    <div class="ui-panel-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
                        <p:commandButton value="xxx" />
                    </div>
                </f:facet>
                Content here
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't put tags inside EL, do it like this :

```
<p:panel id="JunglePanel" header="Jungle">
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton action="#{JungleBean.navigate}" ajax="false" value="Navigate" />
    </f:facet>
</p:panel>
```

Comment: i tried but it didn't work, it didn't made a gray one like the one in the header

Comment: That was not your question, and this is the only way. If it is a matter of styling, why not simply do it in plain HTML/CSS ?

Comment: ok i tried that <h1 class="title ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">         <p:commandButton action="#{JungleBean.navigate}" ajax="false" value="Navigate" />
</h1> but it also didn't work!

Comment: What is not working? The button action? Do you have a h:form arround it or arround the p:panel?

Comment: Specify your actual issue whether it is concern of displaying button or navigation?

Answer (score 0):

That facet is not dialogs's, it belongs to form, take it outside.